# React proxy using port 3000 not 8080

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have an MERN stack app which is currently using `localhost:3000` to host the react side of my application and `localhost:8080` to host the express server it gets the data from.

I am able to call certain APIs from my express server such as `localhost:8080/shows` which returns all the shows from my database. On the react side this is done with this code:

```js
async function getAllShows(setShows, setLoading) {
  const response = await fetch("/shows");
  if (!response.ok) {
    const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
    window.alert(message);
    return;
  }
  console.log(response);
  const records = await response.json();
  setShows(records.shows);
  setLoading(false);
}

export default getAllShows;
```

This is the almost identical code for calling my users endpoint:

```js
async function getAllUsers(setUsers, setLoading) {
  const response = await fetch("/users");
  if (!response.ok) {
    const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
    window.alert(message);
    return;
  }
  console.log(response);
  const records = await response.json();
  setUsers(records.shows);
  setLoading(false);
}

export default getAllUsers;
```

I only experience the problems when I want to call `localhost:8080/users`. This seems to always call `localhost:3000/users` which obviously does not return the correct data.
In the package.json file for the react app I have defined the proxy to use the express server on `localhost:8080` and it works correctly for all my other API calls so I am just confused why this one will not work.

package.json:

```json
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
```

The route `localhost:8080/users` works perfectly fine in the browser calling the API directly and it is a valid route with data returned.
[image: localhost:8080/users]

I am using all the same code to retrieve the data so why am I getting such different results?
This is very confusing to me so any help is appreciated thankyou :)

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? What shows up in the network tab of developer tools?

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.` I can tell it's coming from the wrong localhost because I am also console logging the response which is telling me its calling the localhost:3000/users URL: `Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/users', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears to be on thisline in your `getAllUsers` function:

```js
setUsers(records.shows);
```

From what you've shown, `/users` has the property `users` for its data, not `shows`, so the line should be

```js
setUsers(records.users);
```

It seems like you forgot to change this part when you copy/pasted.